# SSRS matrix with subtotals on rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a matrix with months as the column and the following fields for the rows:
rep
team
customer
category

The category field has the following:  Fct, Act, Var, Cum, Prev

I would like to add subtotals for the category row field by each of the categories (Fct, Act, Var, Cum, Prev) in that field.

If someone filters the data, the subtotals would change (similar to an Excel Pivot table).

Can I do this with data in a row using a matrix table?
[image: Example of what the subtotal should look like:]

Answer (score 0):

If you have column groups to push out the date then you can apply filters to one or more column groups. The subtotals will reflect only data that passed through the filter conditions.

Comment: are you saying I should put the field "Cat" as a column?

Comment: No, I assumed you were using column groups for the date ranges. If not you should be able to limit data using a group filter on your row group.

Comment: I want the data to display, per the image above.

Comment: please provide an example of how to apply a group filter on the row group

Comment: Right-Click the group In the bottom left "Row Groups" panel and select the "Group Properties" sub-menu item to open the group dialog. Then select filters from the right list view. It may be easier to add an expression =IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!Param1.Value),-1,Parameters!Param1.Value) so you can set the value to an accommodating expression such as =IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!Param1.Value),-1,myDataSet!MyField.Value). This instructs the filter to filter on -1=-1 when no parameter else field.value=param.value. All your aggregates at the group level and below will only aggregate data in the filter.